# Why does 'rbind.data.frame' convert Date to numeric?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to understand why `rbind.data.frame` converts my dates to numeric format and how do I fix it. Suppose I have the following:

```
v <- list(
          row1=list(col1 = as.Date("2011-01-23"), col2="A"), 
          row2=list(col1 = as.Date("2012-03-03"), col2="B"))
```

Now I try to do:

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, v)
str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ col1: num  14997 15402
 $ col2: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2
```

Why did `col1` become a num? How do I fix it so it properly becomes a `Date` field in `df`.

**NOTE: I would prefer a native R solution but other packages would be interesting to see**

Comment: Simle. `rbind.data.frame` would not do that if it were actually given dataframes. Rather than using `list in the "inner" level of construction, use `data.frame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on 42-'s comment [Rather than using list in the "inner" level of construction, use data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54950735/rbind-data-frame-converts-date-to-numeric#comment96664905_54950735), for this example, you can convert the inner list to a `data.frame`, and then `rbind` works as expected.

```
> d = do.call(rbind, lapply(v, as.data.frame))
> str(d)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ col1: Date, format: "2011-01-23" "2012-03-03"
 $ col2: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `dplyr`

```
> library(dplyr)
> df <- bind_rows(v)
> df
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  col1       col2 
  <date>     <chr>
1 2011-01-23 A    
2 2012-03-03 B
```

Comment: Small note: `bind_rows()` will work on a list of data frames itself without `do.call()`.

Comment: Is there a native R solution? I am using an old version of R which doesn't support `dplyr`